VulkanMemoryAllocatorをWindows10上でg++で利用できる.a形式の静的ライブラリを生成する方法
質問内容
前提部のVMAリポジトリをクローンしてwindow10上でg++でリンクできる形の.a形式の静的ファイルを生成したいのですが、うまく生成できません、
glfwやその他のライブラリと同様に色々試したのですが生成されなずどうしたらいいか知りたいです。
知りたいこと
VMAリポジトリをwindow10上でg++でリンクできる形の.a形式の静的ファイルを生成したい
試したこと
1,GUI版Cmakeを使ってgenerate,configureを実行しましたが、.aファイルが生成されません、
2,README部のコマンドを実行しましたが、Visual studioのnmakeを求められてしまします。
3,buildディレクトリを生成してcmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..を実行して、mingw32-makeを実行しましたが何も生成されません、
4,ChatGPT,Geminiなど主要AIを利用したころ、makefileを書き換える方法や新しく記述する例などを生成しますが、自分の勘ではなか流儀に反してると思い違うと思います
5,glfwライブラリなどの生成方法と同じよう形で色々コマンドをcmake -G "MinGW Makefiles" ..などを試しましたがやり方がわかりません
6,srcディレクトリ内のCMakeFiles.txtを``cmake -S "src" -B "build" -G "Ninja"してbuildディレクトリ内でcmake --build .を実行しましたがコンパイルエラー等が発生します。
前提
VMA:https://github.com/GPUOpen-LibrariesAndSDKs/VulkanMemoryAllocator
環境
OS: windows10
g++,cmake,MinGW
環境バージョン
minGW
>gcc --version
gcc (x86_64-posix-seh-rev0, Built by MinGW-Builds project) 13.2.0
Copyright (C) 2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

cmake
>cmake --version
cmake version 3.29.6

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).


対処方法
そもそも.a静的ライブラリ生成する必要はなく、ヘッダーファイルのみです。
